# How can I get the "Electorate" badge?

Tags: support, badges

The description written in the FAQ reads:

> Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

I voted 671 times on Stackoverflow, and more than 30% of my votes are on questions; the rest would be on answers.

But still there is no "Electorate" badge.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to vote on 600 **questions**, and 25% or more of your total votes have to be for questions.  If only 30% of your 671 total votes are for questions, then you've only voted on about 200 questions.

200 is a few less than 600.

Comment: So that's about 1,800 total votes at the current Q/A ratio.

Comment: @Peter:  Well, the OP could stop voting on answers and just vote on questions for the next 400 votes...  I wouldn't recommend that but it's an option.

Comment: If it requires to vote on 600 questions then whats "25% of Questions", what is the difference between questions and questions.

Comment: @Azhar:  At least one out of every for votes (25%) that you cast must be for a question _and_ you must cast votes on at least 600 questions.

Comment: @James : if I got your answer that It requires to vote on 600 different questions or answers of different questions and 25% of them must be questions.

Comment: @Azhar:  No.  600 of your votes must be on questions.  None of those 600 can be on answers.

Comment: @James... and what about that 25% ratio. How SO relate them with this ratio. "25% or more of total votes are on questions"

Comment: @Azhar: Think of the 25% ratio comes like this: For every three answers you vote on, you must vote on at least one question. After you've voted on exactly 600 questions, if you've voted on 1800 answers or less, you'll get the Electorate badge, because you will have voted on 2400 posts total, of those 600 would be questions, and at least 25% of your votes would be on questions verses answers. (2400/4 = 600). Of course as @James McNellis says you could also just stop voting on answers altogether and vote on ~400 more questions...

Comment: @James: Sadly, some badges encourage bad behavior.

Answer (score 13):

You need to vote on 600 questions.  In addition, at least 25% of your total votes must be those 600 questions.