# Where is my Electorate badge?

Tags: bug, electorate-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the “Electorate” badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67439/how-can-i-get-the-electorate-badge)

I have seen an `Electorate` badge which is awarded on voting 600 times. as per document says`Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions`. I have cast 606 votes in which 227 are on question and else are on answers. I have downvoted 4 times. But I am not awarded this badge.  Any one have an idea?

Comment: See also the [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67399#67399). Examples are provided for Electorate.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> Electorate: Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

So there are two requirements for this badge that must both be met:

1. You must have at least 600 votes on questions.
2. At least 25% of your total votes must be cast on questions.

#### Examples

- 500 Question and 200 Answer votes, **No** badge, you need 100 or more question votes more.
- 600 Question and 2000 Answer votes, **No** badge, 600/2600 < 1/4, you need at least 67 votes on questions more.
- 600 Question and 1400 Answer votes, **Electorate**, you get the badge.

According to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526367/awais-qarni) you have 606 total votes, not necessarily over 600 votes on questions. So please have a little more patience.

Comment: My dear I think you didnt read my question. My question percentage is 45 percent.

Comment: @Awais: You don't meet the requirements. You haven't voted on 600 questions. You've only voted on 227 questions. Check the "by type" column.

Comment: @Awais Qarni, there are two requirements for the badge, your percentage is good. But you need at least 600 votes on questions alone. Now you have 227 on questions so you still need 373.

Comment: @CodyGray: how can one see the total count or ratio between up down votes?

Comment: Could you, for example, have 600 Question votes and 0 Answer votes?

Comment: Where can I find the "by type" column mentioned by @CodyGray?

Comment: Profile pages have undergone at least two *major* redesigns since 2011, when I left that comment, @Chrisuu. But, you can still find the breakdown of your votes on questions and answers at the bottom of your profile's "Activity" tab, under the section labeled "Votes cast". (At least, I think that's what you're asking.)